# pyinstaller doesn't execute subprocess command

Tags: python

I ran pyinstaller on a .py file and everything works except for one line that calls another .py file via the subprocess command. Here is my code for the .py file with the subprocess line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


import PySimpleGUI as sg
import subprocess

py_file_path = "C:\\Users\\PIN CM 5\\Documents\\Python_Scripts\\Master_Script_v2.py"
gif_file_path= "C:\\Users\\PIN CM 5\\Desktop\\Bryant\\Wait Gifs\monkey.gif"

layout = [[sg.Text('Choose Report')],
      [sg.Listbox(values=('Industry Review (all)', 'Kia_IP', 'Hyundai_IP', 'Mitsu_IP','Acura_IR', 'Honda_IR', 'Hyundai_IR', 'Kia_IR', 'Mazda_IR','Mitsu_IR'), size=(40, 5))],
      [sg.Text('[Required] Enter report date (YYYYMM):'), sg.InputText()],
      [sg.Text('Refresh Cube?'), sg.Combo(['Yes', 'No'], default_value = 'No')],
      [sg.Text('Month-end or MTD?'), sg.Combo(['Month-end', 'MTD'], default_value = 'MTD')],
      [sg.Text('[MTD] Enter share data through (YYYYMMDD):'), sg.InputText()],
      [sg.Text('[MTD] Enter spend data through (YYYYMMDD):'), sg.InputText()],
      [sg.Text('[MTD] Enter month-end forecast (no commas):'), sg.InputText()],
      [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]]

window = sg.Window('Create Decks', layout)

while True:
event, values = window.Read()
inputs_list = ['report_name', 'report_date', 'refresh_cube', 'monthend_or_MTD', 'share_date', 'spend_date', 'forecast']
inputs_dict = {}
for i, input in enumerate(inputs_list):
    if i == 0:
        inputs_dict[input] = values[i][i]
    elif values[i] == '':
        inputs_dict[input] = "0"
    else:
        inputs_dict[input] = values[i]
if event is None or event == 'Exit' or event == 'Cancel':
    break
else:
    sg.PopupAnimated(gif_file_path, message='Just a sec...', background_color='#FFF', font=("Helvetica",18), keep_on_top=True)     
    subprocess.call(['python', py_file_path , inputs_dict['report_name'], inputs_dict['report_date'], inputs_dict['refresh_cube'], inputs_dict['monthend_or_MTD'], inputs_dict['share_date'], inputs_dict['spend_date'], inputs_dict['forecast']])
    sg.PopupAnimated(image_source=None)
    sg.Popup("Complete.\nPlease go to Desktop -> Monthly Automation -> Output", keep_on_top=True)
window.Close()


# In[ ]:
```

I ran this in a command prompt and it executed fine:

```
python "C:\\Users\\PIN CM 5\\Documents\\Python_Scripts\\Master_Script_v2.py" Kia_IP 201909 No Month-end 0 0 0
```

This issue came up after I migrated the process to a new computer (the old one had the user 'PIN' while this new one is 'PIN CM 5' but adding quotes should have solved that issue, I believe). Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try running in a python shell on the target PC `p = call([...])` your command, and see what `p` is equal to - it should be a tuple, the second item a 0 or 1. That Is the exit code

Comment: What happens exactly? Does it crash?

Comment: @Legorooj I get an integer type on p when I run p = subprocess.call([...]) what does this mean?

Comment: @RobertKearns No crash - it finishes execution and I get the popup "Complete. ..." at the end of the script.

Comment: What's the value of it? That is the exit code - 0 for good, 1 for fail

Comment: If it's a one, try `subprocess.getoutput(cmd_as_a_single_string)` that will allow you to catch any errors